# Using submodules with bare repository fails

Tags: git, git-submodules

I'm following [this](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/dotfiles) guide for storing dotfiles. I pushed all my dotfiles from my first computer, including submodules.
I added submodules like this:

`config submodule add https://github.com/Aloxaf/fzf-tab .cache/zsh/plugins/fzf-tab`,

where `alias config='/usr/bin/git --git-dir=$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/cfg --work-tree=$HOME`.

After cloning my repo in `$HOME/cfg` on destination computer with `git clone --bare --recursive my-repo-ssh .config/cfg` , and doing `config checkout` and then `config submodule update --recursive`, i get message "cloning into `home/user/.cache/zsh/plugins/fzf-tab` which I thought is good.

But, in `.cache/zsh/plugins/fzf-tab` directory there is only `.git` file with one line: `../../../../.config/cfg/modules/.cache/zsh/plugins/fzf-tab` (it's the place where I cloned the bare repository).

Why is this happening? I couldn't find anywhere how to use submodules properly with bare repos. Thanks in advance.

Comment: submodules are just links. In addition, they don't have a .git folder, but just a text file stating in a line that the .git folder is shared in the .git of the superproject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it with:

```
git clone --bare --recurse-submodules my-repo-ssh .config/cfg
config checkout -f
config submodule update --init --recursive
```